# Outlook add-in or Microsoft Exchange: It can delete elements from the body of the email?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I've been trying to see in the documentation of Outlook add-in for possibility to delete elements from the body of the email.
I also tried by using by Microsoft Exchange. But they also don't way to delete elements.
I saw secondary services like CodeTwo that offers way to delete elements from the body of email. But that means paying I secondary service. Is there another way that I didn't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you what message body elements to delete, you just need to use the `setAsync` and `getAsync` methods for setting and getting correspondingly the message body. See [Insert data in the body when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/insert-data-in-the-body) for more information.

Also you may find the [UpdateItem operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateitem-operation) from EWS helpful which is used to modify the properties of an existing item in the Exchange store.